# How to make a C# library

Tags: c#

I am relatively new to programming and I am trying to create a library so that I can use my commonly used methods in different projects without having to find the last time I used it and copy paste. 
I tried using  the process outlined at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio but the method which worked in  my console app produced an error. The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UtlityLibraries
{
    public static class NumberLibrary
    {
        public static int[] InitializeNumArray()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a series of numbers seperated by spaces");
            string[] Numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] userArray = Array.ConvertAll(Numbers, int.Parse);
            return userArray;
        }
    }
}
```

When I entered this code in the library it produced the following error:

Error  CS0117  'Array' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertAll'

I would greatly appreciate it if someone would be generous enough to take the time to show me where I went wrong and/or outline the process involved in creating a C# library.

If it makes any difference I'm using visual studio 2017.

Comment: What `using` statements do you have at the top of the file?

Comment: You'll need to reference whatever namespace has `.ConvertAll()` in it at the top of your page. `using System;` I think or using `using System.Array;`

Comment: `Console` also lives in `System`, so it's actually pretty hard to produce this particular error. What does your whole file look like?

Comment: Do you have your own class called `Array`?  That would be one way to get this error.

Comment: Please don't take this too harshly but that method really doesn't look like a good candidate for a library method. It's tied to the `Console` to directly do input and output, so useless for using in e.g. a Forms application, and it has a *fixed* prompt. What if your next program doesn't want to say *exactly* the same thing to the user? (It also assumes user input is perfect, and I'm sorry to say, users aren't perfect)

Comment: @Amy, Putting `using System.Array;` didn't seem to fix the problem. As I said it worked in a normal console app where the only real difference I can see is that it is a console app as opposed to a library. @Damien, I get what you're saying, but this is more for the purpose of educating me then anything else; at the moment all the apps I write are console apps so being tied to the console is fine. I do not intend for these apps to be used by anyone so I didn't bother ensuring user input fit.

Comment: @StephendenBoer I did not suggest you add `using System.Array`.  I asked if you had an `Array` class defined in your code.

Comment: @amy, sorry that was Sean, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely that error is caused by a missing import at the top of your code. Try to put `using System;` or `using System.Array;` at the top of the code.

However since you're trying to make a library of commonly used functions, I have a few more suggestions on how you could edit your code.

This function doesn't really need to exist in a library as it can be done in one line of code like below:

```
int[] convertedNums = Array.ConvertAll(numbers, int.Parse);
```

But if you want to do this for a learning exercise then you shouldn't really be handling keyboard input in a library function, this should be done elsewhere then passed into the function as a parameter. Also arrays are fine to use however probably easier and better to use lists instead. So you could end up with something like this:

```
    public static List<int> InitializeNumArray(string[] nums)
    {
        List<int> convertedNums = new List<int>();
        foreach (string s in nums)
        {
            convertedNums.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
        }
        return convertedNums;
    }
```

And can call this function like this:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a series of numbers seperated by spaces");
    string[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    List<int> numberList = InitializeNumArray(numbers);
```

Comment: And, of course (but this is several lessons further) `InitializeNumArray` could just be written as `.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToList()`. It's not the sort of thing you write a custom reusable method for these days.

Comment: @JeroenMostert true there are several nice one liners which would do!